How to interpret 說明了
This is from a mock exam for Taiwan's TOCFL test.

這本書告訴我們兩件事：快樂是需要練習的；再則，追兔子的狗，比躺在門廊上睡覺的狗更快樂！這原理並非為捉到兔子能令人快樂，而是當我們為突破挑戰與困境而忙碌時，往往能從中發現自己的才能，找出更多存在的價值。這也說明了為何許多不需要克服難題的有錢人，其實並不快樂。

I'm not sure how I should understand the 了 after 說明. Does the sentence mean "this" has actually been the reason for the unhappiness of many rich people in the past, or could it be interpreted as a general statement that would be translated with the simple present in English, as "This explains why ..." I think the latter interpretation is much more natural in this context, but then again, why 了 should be there?

The 了, in this context, is something like "should" or "also"

The presence or absence of 了 in this case is a matter of discourse intent.
In either case, the natural translation into English would use the present (i.e., "...explains why...).
From an English perspective, we need to establish a tense.  The situation is a generic one that extends from the past into the present and is expected to be valid in the future.  In this situation, English speakers typically use the simple present as a default tense.
From the Chinese perspective, tense is not the primary concern, but rather aspect.  We have a situation that can be seen as ongoing or as complete.  With verbs of communication, the emphasis is normally on the content.  In such situations, using 了 is inappropriate, since it establishes a point of reference after the content is given and complete.  Such placement shifts attention away from the content as it was delivered and places it on the completion of the delivery.  In those few cases  where the emphasis is indeed on the deliver and not on the content, 了 is appropriate.
Compare 他说了他来 with 他说他来.  The first communicates that he did say he was coming.  The focus is on declaring that the communication took place.  The second version communicates what was said.  The focus is on the content of the communication as it was delivered.

這也說明了為何許多不需要克服難題的有錢人，其實並不快樂

This statement with 了 has the purpose of highlighting why the principle referred to by 這 is important and powerful.  It is the equivalent of saying: "This is such a  powerful principle that it can explain a fact that we already know, which is that many rich people are not happy...."  The focus of the statement is on the explaining.

這也說明為何許多不需要克服難題的有錢人，其實並不快樂

This statement without 了 has the purpose of introducing something else that the principle entails, i.e., that rich people are not happy...."  The focus is on this new fact that the reader may not have realized.

這也說明... - This also illustrates...(something that as seeing now)
這也說明了.... - This also has illustrated....(something that, has observed thru time or occurred in the past, as seeing now)

在这里，了是用作语气助词，这里的了可以省略掉，说明 和 说明了 是一样的意思，都可以用英语中的 explain 来理解，没有任何本质的区别。
